# Stop thread execution until API async thread completes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, reminders

I am currently looping through a range of dates and caching the `EKEvents` and `EKReminders` associated with each date. The issue that I am having is that when I fetch the `EKReminder`, the API runs asynchronously. The issue is that I am needing to access the contents of that thread, from my current dispatch thread queue. I created a local variable and __block'd it so that I can assign the contents of the API async to it, and then I wrapped the whole fetch invocation in a dispatch_sync call, hoping that it would hold up my current queue until the async was completed but that does not happen. How can I stop my current thread until the async API call is completed?

I provided two comments below in the code to show you the locations where I need to stop the code execution and wait.

```
- (void)setupCalendarCache {
    // Dispatch the queueing of previous days to a background thread
    dispatch_queue_t previousDaysCacheQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
    dispatch_async(previousDaysCacheQueue, ^{
        NSLog(@"Preparing to cache previous calendar days.");

        int reverseYearsToCache = (HZ_NUMBER_OF_TOTAL_YEARS_TO_CACHE * 365) / 2;
        DEDateUtility *dateUtility = [[DEDateUtility alloc] init];
        NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

        dispatch_apply(reverseYearsToCache, previousDaysCacheQueue, ^(size_t i) {
            @synchronized (self.datesOnCalendar) {
                NSLog(@"synchronizing calendar dates.");

                // Setup start and end time for event & reminder fetching.
                NSDate *date = [dateUtility adjustDate:self.currentDate byNumberOfDays:i-1];
                NSLog(@"Working date %@", [date description]);

                [self.datesOnCalendar insertObject:date atIndex:0];

                // Start of the day
                NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
                dateComponents.hour = 0;
                dateComponents.minute = 0;
                dateComponents.second = 0;
                NSDate *startDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:date options:0];

                // End of the day
                dateComponents.hour = 23;
                dateComponents.minute = 59;
                dateComponents.second = 59;
                NSDate *endDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:date options:0];

                // Collections for the reminders and events fetched.
                NSArray *events = [[NSArray alloc] init];
                // Must be blocked so that the Block thread can access it even after this method is completed.
                __block __strong NSArray *remindersList = [[NSArray alloc] init];

                NSLog(@"Building predicates.");
                // Predicates for fetching the reminders and events.
                NSPredicate *fetchPredicateForEvents = [self.eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:startDate endDate:endDate calendars:[self.eventStore calendarsForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent]];
                NSPredicate *fetchPredicateForReminders = [self.eventStore predicateForIncompleteRemindersWithDueDateStarting:startDate ending:endDate calendars:[self.eventStore calendarsForEntityType:EKEntityTypeReminder]];

                // Fetch the events matching the aforementioned NSPredicate.
                events = [self.eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:fetchPredicateForEvents];
                // Don't store a nil array in the dictionary.
                if (!events) {
                 events = [[NSArray alloc] init];
                    NSLog(@"No events found for this day.");
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"Found %d events.", [events count]);
                }

                // ISSUE: Need to block execution until the following dispatch_sync is completed. How can I do this?
                NSLog(@"Running reminders block.");
                dispatch_sync(previousDaysCacheQueue, ^ {
                    // Fetch the reminders matching the aforementioned NSPredicate.
                    [self.eventStore fetchRemindersMatchingPredicate:fetchPredicateForReminders completion:^(NSArray *reminders) {
                        if (reminders ) {
                            remindersList = reminders;
                            NSLog(@"Found %d reminders (%d)", [remindersList count], [reminders count]);
                            return;
                        }
                    }];
                });

                NSLog(@"Building dictionaries for events and reminders.");
                // CANT DO THIS. API async invocation is still taking place.
                //Place the events and reminders in the dictionary
                NSDictionary *eventsAndRemindersForDay = @{@"events": events, @"reminders" : remindersList};
                [previousEventsAndReminders setObject:eventsAndRemindersForDay forKey:[date description]];

                for (int index = 0; index < [remindersList count]; index++) {
                    EKReminder *reminder = remindersList[index];
                    NSLog(@"reminder: %@", reminder.title);
                }
            }
        });
        self.cachingStage += 1;
    });
```

}

Comment: I am wanting to wait until the [self.eventStore fetchRemindersMatchingPredicate:completion^()] is completed. The completion block is async, and I want to force my queue to wait until the async completion block is completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the code that comes after the `dispatch_sync()` Block into the completion Block for `fetchRemindersMatchingPredicate:`. Waiting to do something until an asynchronous task is done is exactly what a completion Block is for.

Also, don't make `dispatch_sync()` calls to the current queue. It is guaranteed to deadlock a serial queue, and has a high chance even when the queue is concurrent.

Comment: I will make the change,though I don't really like placing code that doesn't belong to that completion block inside of it (such as adding the events I acquired to the dictionary within my reminders completion block). However, I'll go ahead and give that a shot to get my project moving forward. For educational purposes on my end, what do you mean by deadlocking a serial queue? I thought the whole point of dispatch_sync() was that your current queue would stop until the dispatch_sync was completed. If I run dispatch_sync on a different queue, will the current queue still wait for it to complete?

Comment: A serial queue won't _start_ the next task until the current one has completed (a concurrent queue may). Dispatching a task synchronously means that the current task won't _end_ until the _new_ task has completed. If you combine those, you end up deadlocked -- the new task can't start until the current task ends, which it can't do until the new task ends.

Comment: It _does_ belong in that Block. You can't do it until the fetch completes. That's the situation that the completion Block is _designed to handle_.

Comment: The GCD documentation on Dispatch Queues says that each queue runs concurrently. So if I put the dispatch_sync on a different queue, am I guaranteed that the code it runs will be completed before it returns to the code executing on the "previousDaysCacheQueue" queue?

Comment: You posted your message while I was typing mine lol. Your explanation makes sense, thanks for the help. I'll get my code changed. Thanks again!

Comment: Queues run entirely separately with respect to each other, yes. And, yes, if you `dispatch_async(q1, ^{ [self carvePumpkin]; dispatch_sync(q2, ^{ [self findCandle]; }); [self illuminateJackOLantern];);` you won't light the Jack O'Lantern until after you've located the candle, but the same is true for `dispatch_async(q1, ^{ [self carvePumpkin]; [self findCandle]; [self illuminateJackOLantern];);` You only need the `dispatch_sync()` if you need to wait for somethng that _must_ happen on a different queue. Further, it doesn't change the synchronous/asynchronous nature of whatever's contained...

Comment: in its task: `dispatch_async(q1, ^{ [self carvePumpkin]; dispatch_sync(q2, ^{ dispatch_async(q3, ^{[self findCandle];});  }); [self illuminateJackOLantern];});` means "wait until the Block containing `[self findCandle]` is _enqueued_", not until it _runs_. This applies directly to your use of a method that does a fetch in the background. The message send itself is run, the method spins off its own task, and then `dispatch_sync()` returns because the method has returned.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Learned a lot from this, helped out a ton!